# Schedule Job for file change notifications

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-background

I want to be notified when a specific file changes. I was looking into `FileObserver` but after having read the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44543756/805673), I've tried to accomplish my target with a `JobScheduler` that should run the job when the file changes, using [`addTriggerContentUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#addTriggerContentUri(android.app.job.JobInfo.TriggerContentUri)).

I started by copying the example from the documentation page, changing the `Uri` that should trigger the job to `Uri.fromFile(File(<path-to-file>))`. Unfortunately, my `onStartJob()` method is never called although `JobScheduler::schedule()` returns success.

Now, I am wondering if I've done anything wrong or if there is a general flaw in my interpretations, maybe it is just impossible to trigger a job on ordinary file changes?

The stripped-down version of my class/code looks like this (Kotlin):

```
class FilechangeService : JobService() {

    companion object {

        private const val JOB_ID = 0

        // Schedule this job, replace any existing one.
        fun scheduleJob(context: Context) {

            // JobInfo Builder to construct the Job
            val builder = JobInfo.Builder(
                JOB_ID,
                ComponentName(context, FilechangeService::class.java)
            )
            // Look for changes to specific file
            val uri = Uri.fromFile(File(<path-to-file>))
            builder.addTriggerContentUri(
                JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(uri, 0)
            )
            val jobInfo = builder.build()
            val js = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler::class.java)
            val status = js.schedule(jobInfo)
        }
    }

    override fun onStartJob(params : JobParameters) : Boolean {
        // Code that is never executed =(
        return false
    }
}
```

Of course, `FilechangeService::scheduleJob()` is called from an other part of my application. Furthermore, I have added the Service to my AndroidManifest.xml with `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"`.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `addTriggerContentUri` works only with "content" `Uri`s - those that start with `content://`

Comment: I feared something like that. Is it possible to convert a File into such a "content" ``Uri``?

Comment: no, there is no such way, I don't know why you don't want to use `FileObserver`?

Comment: The thread mentioned at the beginning of my question says that ``FileObserver`` is not reliable because Android could stop that process at any time.

Comment: so use a [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services), foreground service

Comment: I dislike the mandatory notification that has to be shown to the user when using a foreground service (just for observing a single file), but it seems to me that there is just no other way to achieve what I want ...

Comment: yes, you have to live with that ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up what has been said in the comments, it seems to be impossible to do what I tried to achieve. This is due to the fact that the `Uri` has to be a "content Uri", so a "file Uri" seems to be invalid.